# DBMS_SQL.Execute and BULK update - Need Help

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlbulkcopy

I have this query

> select col1, col2 from table where
>   critera = :criteria_var

The particular query was being used in DBMS_SQL to open cursor and **BIND** the variables. The values are then being fetched by DBMS_SQL functions which are then updating another table. but this is happening one row at a time.

I want to use BULK FETCH INTO. I have read the tutorials but i couldn't find anythign where i can use BULK FETCH INTO with DBMS_SQL.

is it possible? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BIND_ARRAY procedure in the DBMS_SQL package to do a bulk fetch.  There is [an example of this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i997061) in the DBMS_SQL documentation.

Unless there is a particular need to use DBMS_SQL, however, (and assuming dynamic SQL is actually necessary in the first place) it seems likely that it would be easier to use native dynamic SQL, i.e.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableName WHERE criteria = :1'
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_col1_collection, l_col2_collection
  USING l_criteria_variable;
```

If you are just fetching the data from this query in order to update a different table, however, it would be more efficient to just let Oracle do that work by constructing a single UPDATE statement that used this query to fetch multiple rows.  Something like

```
UPDATE destination_table dest
   SET (col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, col2
                         FROM source_table_name src
                        WHERE criteria = l_criteria_variable 
                          AND src.key_column = dest.key_column)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM source_table_name src
                WHERE criteria = l_criteria_variable 
                  AND src.key_column = dest.key_column)
```

Comment: @alee - OK.  Then let me take a step back.  Why do you need to use dynamic SQL (and the DBMS_SQL package)?  Do you not know the table name at compile time, for example?

Comment: I know the table from where to fetch the data. The given column values will be updated in another table through a **dblink**. the last code that you have written (single update statement), wouldn't be slow? compared to bulk update or something?

Comment: A single UPDATE (barring the optimizer doing something horribly stupid) should be the most efficient way to update data.  PL/SQL bulk processing is faster than PL/SQL row-by-row processing but just because it's minimizing context shifts between SQL and PL/SQL.  Doing everything in SQL eliminates context shifts and is the most efficient path available.